# how to transform recursive expressions?

Tags: antlr4

in the anltr4 java grammar(https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/Java.g4) I would like to know when I have the complete expression.  In this example I am trying to make a transformation similar to the following:

```
from: String foo = bar + ", " + baz + "; are true";
to:   String foo = String.format("{0}, {1}; are true", bar, baz);
```

The trouble begins in the declaration from the grammar:

```
expression ('+'|'-') expression"
```

which is a child of expression as well.  Given the example above, the callbacks will look something like the following:

```
0: exp0:bar, exp1:","
1: exp0:bar ",", exp1:baz
2: exp0:bar "," baz, exp1:"; are true"
```

I am targeting the line using a #alias btw.  So what I am awkwardly saying is - how do I use a listener to be able to grab the entire expression when a rule is expressed recursively in order to transform the entire expression?  Or is there another way that I haven't seen yet?

Comment: Could you try to clarify? I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: Sorry I've updated my question.  I originally typed it on a mobile device... not very good for context.